# Event bus for only one view

Tags: vue.js

I need to create an event bus that only works on one page, this is important because I have several pages(views) with the same event listener names. Also some components are also consist of components and I cannot just use global event bus. Which approach would you take?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. It works for one component if you emit an event from there. If you emit an event globally, use namespaces to not have name collisions.

Comment: do you need an eventbus or have you yet to learn @something="", this.$emit('something')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solution using event bus, I would give the component a prop as identity, let's name it `customId`. You can use library such as `nanoid` for default value, and set custom one for your target page

```
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: {
    customId: {
       type: String,
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      innerId: this.customId || nanoid(),
    }
  }
}
```

in your target page

```
<my-component custom-id="event-listener" />
```

In your event bus, add component's `customId` as a part of your message, so in each instance of `MyComponent`, only the targeted one would pick up the data

```
YourEventBus.$emit('custom-event', {
  target: 'event-listener',
  payload: yourData
});
```